# Symfony login encoding password

Tags: php, symfony, encoding, authentication

I'm new to Symfony and I'm trying to set up a login using email only (no username) with Symfony 3.2.
I don't use FOSUserBundle because it's not really helpful for my project. I've been trying to create an user through my controller, it's working fine and add my user in my DB, but the authentification always show me the "Bad credentials" error.

Here is my User entity :

```
<?php
namespace GR\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="utilisateur")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="GR\UserBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->salt = base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), 16, 36);
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="telephone", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $telephone;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="salt", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $salt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="roles", type="array")
     */
    private $roles = array();

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="GR\BackOfficeBundle\Entity\Client", inversedBy="utilisateurs")
     */
    private $client;

    //getters & setters + UserInterface empty methods
```

Here is my security.yml file :

```
security:

    encoders:
        GR\UserBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_OPERATEUR, ROLE_COLLABORATEUR]
        ROLE_OPERATEUR: ROLE_COLLABORATEUR
        ROLE_COLLABORATEUR: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_DESTINATAIRE: ROLE_USER
    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
    providers:
        back_office:
            entity:
                class: GR\UserBundle\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        back_office:
            pattern: ^/back-office
            anonymous: ~
            provider: back_office
            form_login:
                login_path: gr_bo_login
                check_path: gr_bo_login_check
                default_target_path: gr_bo_home
            logout:
                path: gr_bo_logout
                target: gr_bo_login
            remember_me:
                secret: "%secret%"

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/back-office/login.*, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/back-office.*, roles: ROLE_COLLABORATEUR }
```

Here is my login form :

```
{% extends "GRUserBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% block log_content %}
    {% if error %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ error.message }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="{{ path('gr_bo_login_check') }}" method="post">
        <label for="email">Email :</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="_email" />

        <label for="password">Mot de passe :</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Connexion" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is my SecurityController :

```
<?php

namespace GR\UserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use GR\UserBundle\Entity\User;

class SecurityController extends Controller {

    public function loginAction(Request $request) {
        if ($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('gr_bo_home');
        }

        $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

        return $this->render('GRUserBundle:Security:backoffice_login.html.twig', array(
                    'error' => $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError()
        ));
    }

}
```

And here is what I did to create my user :

```
$user = new User();

$user->setNom('Test');
$user->setEmail('admin@admin.fr');
$user->setRoles(array('ROLE_ADMIN'));
$user->setPassword('admin');
$encoder = $this->container->get('security.password_encoder');
$encoded = $encoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPassword());
$user->setPassword($encoded);

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

I encoded my user password according to [this doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/password_encoding.html)

In my DB, the user created is like this :

```
id: 4
client_id : null
nom : Test
telephone: null
email : admin@admin.fr
password : nhDr7OyKlXQju+Ge/WKGrPQ9lPBSUFfpK+B1xqx/+8zLZqRNX0+5G1zBQklXUFy86lCpkAofsExlXiorUcKSNQ==
salt: 
roles: a:1:{i:0;s:10:"ROLE_ADMIN";}
```

As I'm new to Symfony, I assume this is a stupid issue, I know there is a lot of posts about that, but I really didn't find what I need, I think my security.yml is ok, but I'm really not sure about my controller or my User entity.
If you need any more informations, don't hesitate !

Thank's for your help !

Comment: I think you are little bit lost, actually it's simple I advice follow Symfony's authentication with Guard document step-by-step https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html

Comment: $encoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPassword()); should be $encoder->encodePassword($user->getPassword(),$user->getSalt());

Comment: @ugurerkan The Guard System seems very different from what I saw until now, how can I set up a login using mail if the property is set to ApiKey (maybe my question is stupid, I feel a bit lost as you said)

Comment: @Cerad This isn't working, the first argument of encodePassword() is supposed to be a UserInterface, not a string

Comment: @AKM - No.  Check the password encoder interface.  I would not be surprised if you had additional problems but the encoder interface is fact.

Comment: You might be reading some tutorial and confusing the password encoder with the password encoder factory.  Two different concepts.

Comment: @Cerad Well, all I can tell you right now is that when I try to do 
$encoder->encodePassword($user->getPassword(),$user->getSalt‌​()); 
I got the error : 
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoder::encodePassword() must implement interface Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface, string given, called in /var/www/symfony/antoine/gr_logistique/src/GR/UserBundle/Controller/SecurityController.php on line 24 and defined

Comment: Huh.  I am wrong.  Turns out that there is actually two encoder interfaces.  Very strange design decision.  It might be as simple as the fact that you have User::__contrusct() instead of __construct.  Which would also explain why your posted salt is blank.  Once you get things work should consider shifting to a salt free encoder.

Comment: Yes I noticed that one, I changed it to __construct(), but it still doesn't work, I'll change it in my post

Comment: give me your feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] the authentication always show me the "Bad credentials" error.

```
<input type="email" id="email" name="_email" />
```

You have changed the input name but you forgot to update the configuration [`username_parameter`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#username-parameter) under `form_login` ([ref](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#full-default-configuration)).

When you submit the form to `check_path`, the security system will look for a POST parameter with `_username` by default, hence it's empty and "Bad credentials" exception.

You have two options to solve it:

- Update the `username_parameter` with `_email` value.
- Change the input name to `_username` again.

Comment: Thank's a lot, it's exactly what I was looking for :)
My problem is solved :p